# Celery sometimes missed to create tasks

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I have Celery tasks for managing webhook data coming from Slack and Dropbox, every time when someone put a file there. It worked perfectly for both for more than a year. But last 3-4 weeks it seems celery missed to create tasks for Slack, more precisely, create task exactly for every second webhook. Meanwhile, for Dropbox, it still works perfectly. 
I changed CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES from 10s to 200s and seems it started to work, but I'm not sure that this is the solution.

Who else had this problem before?

P.S Celery version is 4.0.2

Comment: Can you show us the code?